# How to replace back slash with forward slash in Jenkins build while using validating string parameter or string parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

1.How to replace back slash with forward slash in Jenkins on UI :- SVN_EAR_PATH (String parameter)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please give more details and post some snippets. Your questions appears to be simple but not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a parameter's value in a freestyle job. When you use git you can use the [Git parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter) to present the user with all the available tags, but I'm not aware of any Subversion alternative unfortunately.

I think your best effort in this case would be to write a pipeline job and then you will have control over the parameter's value (you could write `SVN_EAR_PATH.replace('\\', '/')`)